# java framework for parsing action file

Tags: java, parsing, action, interpreter

Hi
I want to write a program in J2SE that be able to read commands (with their parameters) from some file (Like an XML file)
And then do the corresponding procedure on some given data.
For example if the XML file be:

```
<cut>
     <from>start</from>
     <to>end</to>
</cut>
<reverse></reverse>
<cut>
     <from>
          <find pos="4">tt</find>
     </from>
</cut>
```

My program must get the string then do this:
1. cut string from "start" to "end"
2. reverse sstring
3. cut again from where it finds "tt" after the 4th character to end of string 
and then return this result.

Is There any framework or library to do this? or i should write by my own?
(the form if input file is not important for me i just want it be editable by humans)

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a custom schema? If so, you'd have to write your own parser on top of a generic XML parser like SAX etc.

Comment: @Thomas: what do you mean? I want to do string operations (like cutting,finding,...)

Comment: You define "actions" like "cut" etc. but if that's just something you defined there might be a library that supports it. There might be libraries that support what you want, but the xml grammar might be different (maybe it's called "substring" or similar).

Comment: @Thomas: thats OK ,It doesn't differ for me. i just want to a human be able to understand and edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [Jelly](http://commons.apache.org/jelly/).